# Embedding into finitely presented groups with finite dimensional $K(.,1)$.

Tags: reference-request

Several years ago I saw a paper where somebody proved that a recursively presented group with  2-dimensional aspherical presentation complex embeds into a finitely presented group with (possibly infinite) finite dimensional $K(.,1)$. I cannot find the paper now (I need to refer to it). I thought that the author was Steve Gersten, but he does not remember proving such a result. Anyway, the question is: What was the paper?

Comment: Higman: Subgroups of finitely presented groups, Proc. Royal Soc. Ser. A, vol. 262 (1961), 455-475. The result is that any recursively presented group can be recursively embedded in a fixed f.p. group.

Comment: Yes, I forgot "aspherical", of course. 